# Getting the position of a Node in de Dom

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

i'm using MutationObserver to observe the DOM for insertions or changes of the DOM. But what I want to achieve additionally, is to reproduce the DOM changes in some kind of backend.

Lets say I have the following DOM:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row marketing">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <li>
        <h4>Text</h4>
        <p>More Text</p>
        <button class="add-stuff">Add Element</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h4>Text</h4>
        <p>More Text</p>
        <button class="add-stuff">Add Element</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h4>Text</h4>
        <p>More Text</p>
        <button class="add-stuff">Add Element</button>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On click on a button, the corresponding parent `li` gets a new child element (h1, div, span, whatever). Now the MutationObserver gets fired, and I can get information on the added element (and maybe the children).

For some kind of replay though, I want to get the excact position of the parentNode of the inserted element.

Lets say I press the button of the second element, the DOM changes to

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row marketing">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <li>
        <h4>Text</h4>
        <p>More Text</p>
        <button class="add-stuff">Add Element</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h4>Text</h4>
        <p>More Text</p>
        <button class="add-stuff">Add Element</button>
        <span>Example text</span> <!-- Node has been added -->
      </li>
      <li>
        <h4>Text</h4>
        <p>More Text</p>
        <button class="add-stuff">Add Element</button>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, what I need, is the excact position of this node. For example

```
div.container > div.row.marketing > li[2]
```

What I can't rely on are ID or something like this. I want to use this script on sites, where I don't have control over the DOM, or where is a lot of dynamic data, which makes it very inconvenient to add a unique ID to every element.

I have looked into XPath, which obviously isn't supported natively in javascript.

Does anyone has an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Why not check out react you can monitor changes in state or dom easily via that with its shadow dom

Comment: Why not just store the indexes of the child from the body to your elements ( 3 / 3 / 0 meaning the first child of the fourth child of the fourth child of the body) ? This would be trivial to compute from any element.

Comment: @DasithKuruppu I dont want to use 3rd party dependencies

Comment: @DenysSéguret That is a quite straightforward idea. I'll give it a try